# Регулярное выражение для имени на разных языках

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здесь впервые) Здравствуйте, нужна регулярка, которая допускает все виды букв, в том числе русских, разрешает пробелы, цифры и точки. Это мне нужно для поля full name-полное имя, на многоязычном сайте, т.к могут быть и русские юзера и со всего мира. Благодарю.

Comment: Если допускаются только "...все виды букв, в том числе русских, разрешает пробелы, цифры и точки...", то скрипт и так не пройдет.

Comment: Проще полученные данные сразу проверить на наличие вредных скриптов, ибо регуляркой удобно вытаскивать нужные значения, или например удалять всё, что подойдёт под эту регулярку `<[^>]*>`  
И ограничение поставьте на количество символов вводимых в поле.

Comment: Спорный вопрос. Проще проверить валидность введенных данных по заданным условиям, чем определить наличие скрипта в контенте. В первом случае поле вариантов значительно меньше чем во втором.

Comment: Вот именно, спорный.

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,20}$
как в этом регулярном выражении разрешить пробелы и русские символы?

Comment: Зачем так сложно? Можно: `^[\D][\w\._ ]{1,20}$`

Первый символ буква, остальные : буквы, цифры, подчеркивания, точки, пробелы.

Для "не английских" букв, есть фукнции библиотеки mbstring. Там есть возможность парсить регулярками контент в UTF8. См. ниже.

Comment: ^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9-_.\s]{1,20}$
или вместо \s просто пробел поставить, как писал **KiTE**
Хотя в php с русскими символами лучше **KiTE** послушайте.  
Однако я всё же настою на том что лучше не {1,20}, а ограничение на поле поставить, а то пользователь введёт имя в 100 символов, и не поймёт чё его не принимают, а так будет сразу понятно что больше 20 символов напечатать нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[a-zа-я0-9 _.]+$/gi
```

(Проверял в перле.)

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[\p{L}\p{M}\d\. ]+$/u
```

где `\p{L}` - все буквы;

`\p{M}` - диакритические знаки;

`\d` - цифры;

`\.` - точка;

- пробел.

`^` и `$` нужны, чтобы проверялась вся строка.

Модификатор `u` указывает на то, что работаем в Юникоде.

Возможно, стоит более строго задать регулярное выражение, чтобы первый символ был только буквой

```
/^\p{L}[\p{L}\p{M}\d\. ]*$/u
```

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо подумайте сможете ли вы с русскими буквами потом работать.
Регулярка вот:

```
[\w\s.]+
```

Но мне кажется что вам не это нужно. Более подробно если бы задачу описали, так как эта регулярка почти все что угодно пропустит.
ПС.. в регулярке прописано все в том порядке, который у вас указан.

Comment: В Вашей регулярке нужно экранировать точку, и `\s` - это любой пробельный символ, а по сути вопроса нужны только пробелы.

Comment: Точку не обязательно, \s лишней не будет, она соответствует требованием, чего не скажешь о просто пробеле.

Comment: Точка в паттерне - это любой символ. Если там стоит точка, то это ошибка, потому что теряется смысл регулярки. Она пропустит любую строку.

`\s` - найдет любой пробельный символ, включая пробел, табуляцию, переводы строки и другие юникодные пробельные символы. А по сути вопроса, допустимы только пробелы.

Comment: Я правила знаю, и знаю что такое \s, однако не вижу проблемы.
Точку можно не экранировать в [] пробуй [.]* и что, нашло все символы подряд?

Comment: @trec, `[.]` - это исключение, в наборе символов первый можно не экранировать. Так же `[-]`, `[^]` например. Но в таком виде это действительно _любой_ символ. `[.\w\s]+`, но это езда на исключениях и привыкать к такому не надо. <a href="http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.character-classes.php">пруф</a>

Comment: А проблемы и нет, в скрипте, после проверки все можно обработать. Я говорю о том что, буквально вопрос звучит так:  "...регулярка, которая допускает все виды букв, в том числе русских, разрешает *пробелы*, цифры и точки..."

На счет точки, действительно, работает. Но, на <a href="http://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.character-classes.php">офф. сайте</a> точку в символьном классе рекомендуют экранировать чтобы она не вводила в заблуждение.

Comment: @KiTE отлично)) одну ссылку кинули

Comment: Исключением является только лишь символ "-", так как он служит в [] как обозначение диапазона, все остальные символы, можно не экранировать.
"в базу могут попасть копипасты, например из MSWord" сомневаюсь что кто-то будет в поле с именем копировать из ворда, в любом случае я и настаивал на то чтобы ограничить в поле количество вводимых символов. Но, да, согласен более логично и по тексту и по логике работы брать 1 пробел, хотя тогда их число тоже лучше ограничить одним, ибо в таком синтаксисе их может быть много.

Comment: @KiTE хорошо, с пробелом согласен, просто вы придрались, просто тупо придрались. Если следовать четко по вопросу, то логичнее ставить просто пробел.

@Sh4dow не надо путать! ws без экранирования это всего лишь буквы. И если уж влезли в разговор, и тыкаете носом, то будьте уверены в своей правоте, а не спускайте на тормозах. Признавайте свои ошибки, и соглашайтесь с верным решением. Этот сайт для поиска верных решений. Если докажете что ваше решение есть истинным, а моё нет,то я извинюсь. А до сели, читаните Фридл Дж.—Регулярные выражения  
@KiTE коментить больше не могу, жаль. Выхожу со спора

Comment: Отлично! Тогда почему ваша регулярка не выглядит как `[ws.]+`? В общем, неважно. Мне больше нравится то, что написано в документации.

Comment: >Исключением является только лишь символ "-"
Внимательно читайте документацию. Еще есть `^` и `\`.
>Если следовать четко по вопросу, то логичнее ставить просто пробел.
Об этом и речь. Но если упустить этот момент, в базу могут попасть копипасты, например из MSWord, где может быть целая куча юникодопробельного мусора. И в определенный момент это может вызвать ряд неудобств. Я раз на этом обжегся.

Answer (score 0):

Регулярка: `[\w\. ]+`
Но для обработки нужно использовать функции модуля mbstring иначе будут распознаваться только английские буквы.

Comment: ужас, модификатор <b>u</b> уже не в моде да? -.-

Comment: Кстати, <a href="http://xpoint.ru/forums/programming/PHP/thread/33960.xhtml">вот тут</a> пишут, что при использовании `u` метаcимволы `\w`, `s`, `\d` не работают в диапазоне старше `U+007F`.